# Verb for understanding something so well that it becomes part of your nature

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb that means you understand something so well that this something becomes part of you, your nature, your essence?

The closest I've found is *grok* but I don't like the word for two reasons:

1. The meaning of the word I'm looking for and the meaning of *grok* are similar, but still different.
2. I don't like the etymology of the word (which is a dumb reason for not choosing to use a particular word, but that's just how I am).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: An example, can you provide?

Comment: How about this? http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+one+with _"I am completely at one with Michael on this decision."_

Comment: @NVZ, "be at one" is a verb phrase, not a verb.

Comment: Please write an example sentence where the word would be used. The following is the strict guideline of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Answer (score 5):

The Oxford dictionary (American English) defines [***internalize***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/internalize) as

> - Make (attitudes or behavior) part of one’s nature
>     by learning or unconscious assimilation.
> - Acquire knowledge of (the rules of a language).

See also [What does it mean to “absorb rather than learn”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6964/what-does-it-mean-to-absorb-rather-than-learn) on ELL
for a (somewhat chaotic) discussion of ***absorb***.

Answer (score 1):

**To embody:**
*to include as part of something:
Kennett embodied in one man an unusual range of science, music, and religion.*

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/embody

Answer (score 0):

Colloquially, people sometimes say **"owned,"** as in "I will give you an A on the exam if I feel that you've really owned the material."

Comment: Too informal, I'm afraid. But anyway, thanks for letting me in on that colloquialism - I've never heard of it before.

Comment: There's some possibility that it's a West Coast college professor thing, and this is where I've heard it the most! (Also from West Coast psychologists.)

Answer (score 0):

**Intuitive**

*The more I practice yoga, the more intuitive I find its philosophy.*

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Unfortunately this isn't a verb.

Comment: You may be able to rework this answer to use the slightly controversial verb "intuit". See https://www.thefreedictionary.com/intuit  *Usage Note: Intuit is a good example of a verb that was once considered objectionable but has since become so familiar as to be unremarkable.*

Comment: Good point, thank you. How would you use "intuit" though? Can you actually intuit something?